# How can I initialize an array of a struct inside another struct?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

so I got the following structs:

```
typedef struct typeData{ 
    char name[20]; 
    double weightIn; 
    double weightOut; 
}dataType;

typedef struct fifoTable{ 
     unsigned short int start; 
     unsigned short int end; 
     dataType data[N]; 
} fifoTable;
```

and the following function that is supposed to initialize the structure:

```
fifoTable *initFifo(){
    fifoTable table;
    table.start = 0;
    table.start = 0;
    dataType data[N];
    table.data = data;
    return table;
}
```

The problem I encounter is that I get an error message saying: "assignment to expression with array type". I looked it up so I figured it is not possible to initialize an array inside a struct like this. I found some examples with arrays of char, int etc. But since there are other elements inside the dataType struct, I can't find a way to initialize this table :/ How could I do this?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: You are trying to return a stack variable as a pointer in your initialization code. You should use malloc.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider: There is no stack in the C language. `table` is an automatic variable. But yes, the variable is out-of-life after return, thus any access is UB. This is not the reason for the compiler error, though.

Comment: @Olaf Where can I read about that? This is the first time I've heard that.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider: How about the C standard? Which would be ISO9899:2011, nothing else (just pick the final draft n1570, the standard itself is not avail for free, but the draft is identical in all relevant aspects).

Comment: @Olaf "stack" is common jargon for automatic storage

Comment: @M.M: It is a wrong assumption, though and missleading. `auto` or "automatic" variable is not really more to type. A modern compiler and ABI has just too much optimisations it is safe to assume even `struct`s are always stored on the stack. See AAPCS for an example (passing of small `struct`s).

Comment: @Olaf it's not any assumption, it's just a word. Like how we still use floppy disk icons for "save" buttons

Comment: @M.M: No, it is a problematic missconception. See other questions here which result from this missconception. At least trying to be precise is vital in programming. And if not, a correction should be appreciated and memorised. (And although I fight to the bone for my opinion, I'm very well open to well founded arguments - you should know what I mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work for a number of reasons.

First, an array is not an assignable lvalue.  That means it can't appear on the left side of an assignment as you're attempting to do.

Note that initializing (which occurs at the time a variable is defined) is not the same as assigning.  For example, you can do this:

```
int a[3] = { 3, 4, 5 };
```

But not this:

```
int a[3] = { 3, 4, 5 };
int b[3];
b = a;
```

You're also returning a `fifoTable` from your function while it's declared to return a `fifoTable *`.

What you probably want is to dynamically allocate memory for your struct, zero it out, and return the pointer.  You do that as follows:

```
fifoTable *initFifo(){
    fifoTable *retval = calloc(1, sizeof(fifoTable));
    if (!retval) {
        perror("calloc failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You declare "data" and "table" on stack and return a pointer to it but the scope of those declarations end at function so the pointers are invalid.

If you want to return "fifoTable" then use malloc to allocate storage and return a pointer to that e.g.

```
fifoTable *initFifo(){
    fifoTable* table = malloc(sizeof(fifoTable));
    table->start = 0;
    table->start = 0;
    dataType data[N];
    /* initialize data somehow */
    memcpy(table.data, data, sizeof(table.data));
    return table;
}
```

Comment: Why not set member data directly?

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1**

> the problem ...  "assignment to expression with array type".

```
table.data = data;
```

> I figured it is not possible to initialize an array inside a struct like this.

Code is not *initializing* an array.  Code is attempting to do an *assignment*.

To copy the contents of an array to another array, use `memcpy()`

```
memcpy(table.data, data, sizeof table.data);`
```

**Problem 2**

Function return type is a pointer: `fifoTable *`, yet code attempts to return a structure: `fifoTable`

```
fifoTable *initFifo(void){
    fifoTable table;
    ...
    return table;
}
```

To return a structure (to return a pointer is more common), declare the return type to match

```
fifoTable initFifo(void){
    fifoTable table;
    ...
    return table;
}
```

To return a pointer, return a pointer to valid memroy, perhaps by allocating it.

```
fifoTable *initFifo(void) {
  return calloc(1, sizeof(fifoTable));
}
```

**Problem 3 (title question)**

> How can I initialize an array of a struct inside another struct?

One element at a time.

```
#define N 4

fifoTable initFifo(void) {
  dataType data[N];
  fifoTable table = { 0, 0, {data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]}  };
  return table;
}
```